# android get process name inside BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver

I'm stuck in this trouble and I can't figure it out. I googled a lot, but nothing gave me an answer.

I explain:
I have a BroadCastReceiver which runs in a different process (`android:process=":anotherProcess"`)

I want to get this process name inside my BroadcastReceiver.

In this case for **example**, it could be: `com.my.package:anotherProcess`

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to get the thread name on which your process is running?

Comment: Please answer this question and accept the answer so it doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @harshit No, OP wants to get the name of the process, as stated in the question. Not the name of the Thread (that is something different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way. For anyone who will need this:

```
     int id = Process.myPid();
     String myProcessName =context.getPackageName();

     ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService( context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
     List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

     for(RunningAppProcessInfo procInfo : procInfos) {
         if (id == procInfo.pid)
         {
             myProcessName = procInfo.processName;
         }
     }
```